# How can I save image in my Sugar ORM database?

Tags: android, sugarorm

I want save an image in my database with sugar orm. How can I do this?

I have the next code to try to save it:

Entity:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.orm.dsl.NotNull;
import com.orm.dsl.Unique;

public class Exercise extends SugarRecord {

    @Unique
    protected String name;
    @NotNull
    protected String description;
    protected Drawable image;
    protected String video;

    public Exercise() {
    }

    public Exercise(String name, String description, Drawable image, String video) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.video = video;
    }

    /**
     * @return String name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return String description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return Image image
     */
    public Drawable getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * @param image
     */
    public void setImage(Drawable image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    /**
     * @return String video
     */
    public String getVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    /**
     * @param video
     */
    public void setVideo(String video) {
        this.video = video;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to save with the next code:

```
 Exercise addExercise = new Exercise("Prueba", "Prueba 2", image.getDrawable(),"");
    addExercise.save();
```

Variable image is an ImageView, and the image I will save is an image which is taken in the gallery:

```
if(requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
```

When I try to save appear the next error:

> Class cannot be read from Sqlite3 database. Please check the type of
>   field image(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this

Define

```
protected byte[] image;
```

in Exercise class and also change the type of the image variable in constructor.
Now convert the image into byte array

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,90,stream);
   Byte[] image_byte=stream.toByteArray();
```

Actually storing the entire image in DB is bad idea based on read/write efficiency.It is better to store the image in seperate folder and store the path as a string(varchar) in database